# groovy intelliJ "angle brackets (<>)" modify codestylesettings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, formatting

i am currently having a problem with the codestylesettings i.e. the "Reformat Code" function in IntelliJ.

***NECESARRY INFORMATION:***

I am writing groovy scripts, which use some Java functionality (for example generics)

It appears that my version of groovy (which cannot be changed for various reasons) runs into compile problems when having a variable defined like this:

*NON-WORKING:*

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = a["b"] as List<Map<String, Object>>
```

Problem is that the compiler can only interpret the ***last 2*** closing angle brackets correctly if there is a space between those.

*WORKING:*

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = a["b"] as List<Map<String, Object> >
```

This is a known bug in the version of groovy which i am using.

***PROBLEM:***

The "Reformat Code" functionality always removes the space, which i added between the closing angle brackets in order to make the script compilable.

***QUESTION:***

How can i teach IntelliJ to not remove the space?

***ATTEMPTS:***

This setting does exist for java files (Settings-> Editor -> Code Style -> JAVA -> Spaces -> Within -> Angle Brackets).

Exported XML Settings:

```
<JavaCodeStyleSettings>
<option name="SPACES_WITHIN_ANGLE_BRACKETS" value="true" />
```

But not for groovy, so i tried adding it for groovy like so:

```
<codeStyleSettings language="Groovy">
<option name="SPACES_WITHIN_ANGLE_BRACKETS" value="true" />
```

When reformatting it only freezes for like a minute or so and then removing the spaces again.

Probably cuz groovy is not aware of those angle brackets hence it is Java functionality used here.

Comment: Seems it's not possible. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Can you try adding a `SPACE_WITHIN_GSTRING_INJECTION_BRACES` and see if it helps? The value will be true

Comment: @TarunLalwani i added it like so:

  <GroovyCodeStyleSettings>
    <option name="SPACE_WITHIN_GSTRING_INJECTION_BRACES" value="true" />
  </GroovyCodeStyleSettings>

Didn´t help...

Comment: Per other answers, this is not possible now.  A potential workaround would be to record a macro that first formats code and then replaces all >> with > >.  This would go badly for right shift operators though, if you use those.  You could try to regex it but there's no way to enforce that in a macro.

Comment: It's also technically possible to add a custom language (which maybe you could base on Groovy?) per this: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html but that's a pretty significant undertaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the decompiled source code and it doesn't seem `SPACES_WITHIN_ANGLE_BRACKETS` is supported for `Groovy`. Each formatter has a separate formatting rules and configs. None of the existing configs will help you in your quest

[image: Only for Java]

[image: No Option in Groovy]

As @ybedrov mentioned, you will need to open a enhancement request with [them](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

<s>No existing option will help you</s>

As `@daniel` pointed out, there does exist one way, which is create your own custom language

http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html

But that option is exists in the fairytale world, if you are just concerned about a single space. I would just a `sed` command to fix the issue by running a bash script

```
$ find . -name "*.groovy" | xargs sed 's|>>|> >|g' -i
```

Comment: is there a way to enhance the existing configs?

Comment: No, this is a closed source project, so you can't do anything except ask them to take this as a feature request

Comment: Custom language support *is* included, but is not a "do it yourself in a half-hour" sort of project.  Documentation can be found here: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html

Comment: That would be a lot of effort for a missing space :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a comment in the problematic areas to prevent the formatter from breaking the code. For example:

```
final List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = a["b"] as List<Map<String, Object>/**/>
```

Assuming this works, it's at least better than broken code, although quite ugly.